# Deserializing JSON with dynamic keys into certain type

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I want to deserialize a JSON string into an Version object with the help of [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

History is a dictionary of int keys and TaskObject values. The key is a dynamic number.

Here is a short example of the JSON:

```
[
   {
     "CurrentVersion": 3,
     "TaskObject": {},
     "History": {
       "1": {},
       "2": {}
     },
     "ObjectTypeName": "the type"
   }
]
```

My Class

```
public class Version : Lib.Objects.Task
    {
        public int CurrentVersion { get; set; }
        public Lib.Objects.Task TaskObject { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int, Lib.Objects.Task> History { get; set;} 
        public string ObjectTypeName { get; set; }                          
    }
```

Code

```
string rawJSON;
using (var wc = new WebClient())
    rawJSON = wc.DownloadString(uri);
var version = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Objects.Version>(rawJSON); //throws a JsonSerializationException
```

But I get an exception

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
```

Any ideas how to fix this, so I can deserialize the JSON to a Version object?

## Edit

Turning out that I was receiving a JSON **array**, so I've edited my example.

Comment: are you getting value in rawJSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
string rawJSON;
using (var wc = new WebClient())
    rawJSON = wc.DownloadString(uri);

var versions = new List<Objects.Version>();
foreach (var jToken in JArray.Parse(rawJSON))
    versions.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Objects.Version>(jToken.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can access this using the JObject

```
var jsonString = "{\"CurrentVersion\": 3,\"TaskObject\": { },\"History\": {\"1\": { },\"2\": { }},\"ObjectTypeName\": \"the type\"}";
```

I've "escaped" the back slashes in my example.

```
var jo = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

This seems to deserialize ok. Then I can access the properties via the below

```
jo["CurrentVersion"].ToString()

jo["TaskObject"].ToString()
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, but I realized that I was receiving a JSON array so I've edited my question and already found an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you declare you lib.objects.task as object, it will work. 
Maybe it's enough in your case